# keras RNN running on less samples

Tags: python, keras, recurrent-neural-network

```
x = training_set_scaled
x = x.reshape(-1,1,12)
y = lab.to_numpy()
y = y.reshape(-1,1)

print(x)
print(y)
##(1127, 1,12)
##(1127, 1)

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(units=128,activation='relu',return_sequences=True,
          input_shape=(1,12)))
#model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(LSTM(units = 128,activation='relu'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Dense(100,activation='relu'))
#model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Dense(1,activation='softmax'))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3,decay=1e-5)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=opt,metrics=['accuracy'])

print(model.summary())
model.fit(x,y,batch_size=10,epochs=20,verbose=2)
```

// this is my code but
Epoch 1/20
113/113 - 0s - loss: 7.8614 - accuracy: 0.4845
why it is running on only 113 samples

i am trying to build RNN using keras. n.o samples is 1127 and 12 variables in each.
output is simple 0 or 1 but when i run the model it runs on only 113 samples. can someone please help me. im stuck here for 3 days
thanl you

Comment: Your `batch_size` is `10`. So 113 batches per one epoch will be trained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not running on 113 samples, it is running on '113 mini batches' of size 10 each.

```
model.fit(x,y,batch_size=10,epochs=20,verbose=2)
```

here you have specified the batch size as 10, hence it trains the model using 10 samples 113 times aka 10*113 = 1130 total samples. (it trains the last mini batch on 7 only since those are the only ones left)